# Block / Allow resources loading into Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, trigger.io, ieaddon, forge

It is possible to use the Forge Trigger.IO framework to develop an extension for Internet Explorer that examines resources or HTTP requests before they load and arbitrarily decides to allow or block them?

I assume a possible way of doing this would be by running a content script on 'start' and adding a listener to check for any loading resource, but there should be a better way of doing this. (i.e. Firefox's [nsIContentPolicy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIContentPolicy) or Chrome's [webRequest API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way to do this with forge at present.

On IE content scripts are only injected after the page load has already completed and all page resources have already loaded so you wouldn't be able to intercept resource load events.

It would be a nice feature to have though and I've added it to our wish list.

Comment: @josesigna email us at support@trigger.io so we can discuss options